# fade out on scroll 100px before reaching document height of 100%

Tags: jquery

On scroll a fixed div fades in than when a scroll reaches 100px before document height it needs to start fading out.

please, can someone point out where is a mistake in the code below?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(window).scrollTop()>100) {
    $('#boxcont').fadeIn();
}
else {
    $('#boxcont').fadeOut();
}
if ($(window).scrollTop() + 100 > $(document).height() - $(window).height() ){
    $('#boxcont').fadeOut();
}
});
```

here's [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vmrSY/)

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle example?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed - he's made one - look at the demo link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to make use of jQuery's [`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function. Normally, you will want to use it before the `fadeIn`, as well however, because of how your condition is stated, it would constantly `stop` the `fadeIn` as it is scrolling, so we omit it there for the sake on simplicity.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop()>100) {
        $('#boxcont').fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $('#boxcont').stop(true).fadeOut();
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + 100 > $(document).height() - $(window).height() ){
        $('#boxcont').stop(true).fadeOut();
    }
 });
```

See the new [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmrSY/1/)